# Were quaestors in the Roman Republic entitled to lictors/fasces?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-republic

I apologise if this is too basic a question, but Wikipedia seems to contradict itself! It says here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaestor that a Quaestor was entitled to one lictor and one fasces, but here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursus_honorum it says they wore the *toga praetexta* but had neither lictors nor fasces.

As far as I can see, quaestors were more senior civil servants that  magistrates; they did not possess *imperium*, so why would they have the lictors/fasces?

Comment: As far as I know, they didn't have any.

Comment: By the way, the Quaestors were definitely magistrates, even though they did not possess imperium.

Comment: @Laveran  Can you expand on that a bit, please? I know they are always called magistrates, but, at least in Rome, they seem to be charged with the oversight of financial administration, rather than  justice - to me, that's more a civil servant. Not arguing, just confused!

Comment: @TheHonRose In ancient Rome, the magistrates were not necessarily involved in the judicial system. What they did (finances, justice, public buildings, military command...) matters little, actually. A civil servant would have been hired by the state (rare until the Empire), whereas a magistrate was elected by the people or appointed by the senate. They could have no imperium, but still use their potestas. You might want to see Mommsen "Roman Constitutional Law" for a theoretical analysis of the meaning of magistrates in ancient Rome.

Comment: @TheHonRose In early republic quaestors were connected with criminal proceedings (Livius II, 41, 11).

Comment: @Laveran BTW - I do know quaestors weren't *actually* civil servants - an anachronism, obviously - just that from my preliminary reading they seemed to perform the *functions* of a modern civil servant.

Comment: It seems this still hasn't been corrected, because I just came here to ask the same question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quaestors had neither lictors nor fasces.

Originally quaestors, as the name shows, were a kind of "investigators". But the right to fasces signified a right of deciding life and death, which was only appliable to praetors (i.e. "judges") and higher magistrates, i.e. consuls and dictators.

Also, on the matter of lictors, we perfectly know that even *aediles plebis* had no right to lictors, and only *aediles curules* had two lictors (without fasces!). As quaestors had lower rank compared to aediles, then they obviously had no lictors at all.

Comment: Thanks, that was my suspicion, but in one of the Wikipedia articles it says they were entitled to ONE lictor/fasces, which, without imperium, makes no sense.

Comment: @TheHonRose Seems that _only English_ Wiki says so. Unfortunately, they didn't provide any reference.

Comment: Yes, I know, and as the two articles reference each other, it's doubly confusing!